# saving the contents of NSArray as plain text file and not at xml

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, nsarray

I'm trying to save the content of NSArray as plain text file. Here is How I'm saving the content of the array:

```
[myArrayContent writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

But is been saved as xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>lineOne</string>
    <string>lineTwo</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

My question to you guys is how can I save the content as plain text:

lineOne
lineTwo

Any of you knows how can Implement this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make an array into a string, and save it, like this:

```
NSString *fileContent = [myArrayContent componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];
[fileContent writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Reading back is done like this:

```
NSArray *myArrayContent = [
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
    componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"
];
```

Comment: Deprecated, now you would use something like      [fileContent writeToFile:[self filepath] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

Answer (score 0):

Given the objects in your array are NSStrings you should iterate through the objects in the array and writing the string in each iteration as you do with your array.